# Are there reputable public proving parameters for universal zkSNARK systems?

Tags: zero-knowledge

I have seen that Filecoin performed a public set-up ceremony for their zkSNARK system. Because Filecoin uses the Groth16 prover (which has a circuit-specific set-up), the output of this ceremony was public parameters that anyone can use to prove statements involving one of six Filecoin-defined circuits.

It would be nice if a large and reputable organisation would perform a trusted set-up for universal proving systems, like PLONK or Marlin. Presumably, this organisation would use its resources to attract participation from a wide set of unrelated members of the public, and this would remove the need for smaller projects to redo this work.

My question: are there any universal zkSNARK set-ups that have been completed and released their proving parameters to the public?

If not, why not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about zero-knowledge systems applied to *crypto**currencies*** rather than *crypto**graphy***.

Comment: I disagree with the characterisation. ZkSNARKs are a general purpose tool of cryptography. The mention of Filecoin is an example and not core to the question. In fact, my motivation for this question is unrelated to cryptocurrency.

Comment: Okay, I've retracted my close vote. Would you kindly share your motivation with us? I'm keen to know.

Comment: I am designing an identity protocol that requires ZK proofs to prove authenticity of data and identity attributes. I prefer to use a zkSNARK if there are public parameters available, but if we would need to perform a trusted set-up, then I might just use bulletproofs (in which case there is no trusted set-up but the proof sizes are larger).

Comment: Preliminary answer: it appears that zkSync has performed a universal set-up for PLONK; see https://docs.zksync.io/userdocs/security/#universal-crs-setup

Still, this is not fully satisfactory because I have not seen evidence of any external parties using this set-up for their own purposes. It remains unclear to me whether all powers-of-tau ceremonies (most of which are described in the context of Groth16) are relevant to universal SNARKs.